# Montel's theorem problem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of analytic functions on $D$ such that $Re(f_n) > 0$ and $|f_n(0)-i| < 1/2$.  Show that $f_n$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence on compact subsets of $D$.

My attempt.  If we consider $h_n=e^{-f_n}$ then $h_n$ is uniformly bounded on $D$ and hence, by Montel's theorem, $h_n$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.  Now it seems like we can use the second condition and say that we can take the principal log of $h_n$ to get the desired convergent subsequence of $f_n$.  The issue now is that we can only take the log locally around zero and not on all of $D$.  Is there a way to patch this up?  Maybe instead of taking the log we can stick the function into the disk using some conformal map and use normality there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume that $f_n(0)$ converges and $e^{-f_n}$ converges locally uniformly on $D$. By Hurwitz (I think), if $e^{-f_n}$ converges locally uniformly on $D$ to a holomorphic function $t$ on $D$, then the limit is either zero or has no zeros. But by the hypothesis on $f_n(0)$, we know that $t(0) \neq 0$, so $t$ has no zeros and thus has a logarithm $\ell$ (because $t'/t$ is a holomorphic function on the convex open domain $D$ so has an antiderivative).

Thus $e^{-f_n+\ell}$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions that converges uniformly locally to $1$, and we can thus assume that $f_n(0) \rightarrow \ell(0)$ (up to adding $2ik\pi$ to $\ell$). So if $g_n=f_n-\ell$, $g_n$ is a function on the unit disk such that $e^{g_n}$ converges (locally uniformly) to $1$ and $g_n(0)$ converges to zero, so that the imaginary part of $g_n$ is always (for large enough $n$) between $-i\pi$ and $i\pi$, which entails (through elementary estimates) that $g_n \rightarrow 0$ locally uniformly.